# mysql select query if the curdate between two dates of every month

Tags: mysql

I am trying create a mysql query which will return the result only if like

Today's date is between 25th and end of the month.

I couldn't find a solution or idea how to go about it.

example:

```
SELECT m.member_name     
  FROM member m, `club_name` c 
  WHERE m.cabinet = 1 and c.wmmr_report=0 and m.club_name=c.id and date(curdate) between ...
```

Thanks

Comment: You should learn to use proper join syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need only the day, not the whole date, so you may use

```
SELECT m.member_name     
  FROM member m, `club_name` c 
  WHERE m.cabinet = 1 and c.wmmr_report=0 and m.club_name=c.id and DAY(NOW()) >24
```

[Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)